# Livewire : The POST method is not supported for this route

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I installed Laravel Livewire and followed the installation tutoriel (including scripts etc).

I have a page named /comparateur that have a form and after that shows results on the same page (sql request).

I put the livewire test code (counter) on https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/quickstart

First problem I dont see the characters "+" for increment the counter (maybe css conflict ?).

But real problem is :

```
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
```

I have this when I click on "+".

My routes :

```
Route::get('/comparateur', function () {
    
    return view('comparateur');
})->name('comparateur');




Route::post('comparateur', 'ComparateurController@post')->name('comparateur');
```

app/http/livewire/counter.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Counter extends Component
{
    public $count = 0;

    public function increment()
    {
        $this->count++;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.counter');
    }
}
```

counter.blade.php :

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <button wire:click="increment">+</button>
    <h1>{{ $count }}</h1>
</div>
```

routes/web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

use App\Vpns;
use App\Blog;



Route::group([
    'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
    'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath' ]
],

 function()
{
    Route::get('/', function () {

        return view('welcome');



    });

     Route::group(['prefix' => 'laravel-filemanager', 'middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () {
         \UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Lfm::routes();
     });


    Route::get('go/{nameOfProduct}', ['as' => 'go.to' , 'uses' => 'VpnController@goTo']);


    Route::get('vpn/free', ['as' => 'vpn.free' , 'uses' => 'VpnController@free']);

        Route::get('vpn/tools', ['as' => 'vpn.tools' , 'uses' => 'VpnController@tools']);

     
    Route::resource('/vpn', 'VpnController')->name('*', 'vpn');

    Route::resource('/blog', 'BlogController')->name('*', 'blog');




    Route::get('/aboutvpn', function () {
        
        return view('vpn.about');
    });

    Route::get('/home', function () {
        
        return view('welcome');
    });


Route::get('/comparateur', Counter::class)->name('comparateur');


    Route::post('/comparateur', 'ComparateurController@post')->name('comparateur');





    Auth::routes();

    Route::get('logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () { Route::get('/profile', function() { return view('profile'); }); });
    Auth::routes();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

});
```

edit :

Finally I found an answer. Its because of the localization plugin https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization#installation

It adds /fr /pt /de etc on the URL so the /comparateur page doest not exists but /fr/comparateur yes.

But I dont know how to do to make the website working

Comment: `php artisan route:clear` and try again

Comment: Can you show your livewire component code? And also have you tried to clear the route cache?

Comment: Already did php artisan route:clear : still not working/ I updated my original post. + text is showing its okay it just was white on lightgrey....

Answer (score 1):

To fix, replace

```
Route::get('/comparateur', function () {
    return view('comparateur');
})->name('comparateur');
```

with

```
use App\Http\Livewire\Comparateur;

...

Route::get('/comparateur', Comparateur::class)->name('comparateur');
```

You can still use the controller and render the non-livewire view, and then you could include the view for the component from there if you'd prefer that way.

I'm not actually sure if you could just include the livewire view from the route, I've never tried it.

As for the post link, `Route::post('comparateur', 'ComparateurController@post')->name('comparateur');`, it's not needed, livewire will handle the function call and updating the view itself, you only need the component backend and view.

**Update**

If it's the localisation breaking it (due to the url), does this work?

```
Route::get('/{language?}/comparateur', Counter::class)->name('comparateur');
```

Comment: I dont have a class named Comparateur in Livewire. I just have a counter. I don't understand...

Comment: ah, ok. You should have a php file (in `app\Http\Livewire`) and a blade file. How did you generate the component? I would suggest deleting the existing files and running `php artisan make:livewire comparateur`. Have I taken the `comparateur` thing too far and your component is actually named `counter` and `comparateur`  was only intended to be the url/name of the route?

Comment: Yes it is. I did as you say to generate the counter component, as detailed in the basic usage tutorial on the official website of livewire

Comment: is it still not working? could you update the question with the contents of `routes/web.php` and both files of the component?

Comment: I edited the post for adding de routes/web.php and the others files of the componont are already here

Comment: I found the answer. It was the problem with the translation laravel package that changes all the URLs like host/en host/fr host/pt etc... Now i think I have to add a joker character at my URL like * to make it work. I go to the doc

Comment: I already tried a trick like that but now the URL on the browser is : http://127.0.0.1:8000/fr//comparateur with two // and still not works got an error 404

Answer (score 0):

it seems like  '/comparateur' is not equal to 'comparateur' in your routes